# Java webstart application shortcut is not created on the right desktop

Tags: java, windows, windows-7, java-web-start

first i'll describe the environment i'm working with since it is probably the origin of the problem. I'm using windows7 and i modified the default profile so that every user who will use a computer will have the same setting. To do so i copied the profile i modified and name it Default in the fold C:\Users and then i changed the permission so that it is available for all administrator.

Now, before copying the folder of the profile i was modifying, let's call it "New", i installed a web start java application that is used by our employee and that create a shortcut on the desktop. This is were my problem is, when i put the computer on the network and use a user to log on it everything works fine, the application can be launch no problem but if i delete the shortcut and try to create it again java create the shortcut on the desktop of the local profile "New".

Does anybody have any idea to fix this problem ?

Thank you

Comment: +1 to question. I have the same issue, seems to be permission related.